# resolveconf -u keeps adding an unwanted search domain to resolve.conf

Tags: dns, resolv.conf, static-ip, resolvconf

I have my desktop computer configured with a static IP address:

[image]

However, */etc/resolve.conf* keeps getting overwritten with:

```
nameserver 127.0.0.1
search localdomain example.com
```

This seems to happen periodically or when I run `sudo resolvconf -u`.

I would really like to get `example.com` removed from the dns search domain list.   I used to have it in there but its causing problems now.  I just can't seem to get it out.  I don't know where it is coming from or why it keeps getting put back.  As far as I can grep, there is nothing referring to `example.com` anywhere in my */etc* directory anymore.

What is putting this search domain into my *resolv.conf* file and how can I prevent it from doing so?

Comment: Whats the output of `sudo grep -rn example.com /etc/network/interfaces /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections /etc/resolvconf/` ?

Comment: `example.com` is not found in any of those locations.

Comment: It is possible that a DHCP server is providing it, but I'm not sure how to check that, nor to disable it if that is actually the case.   I would already expect not be using DHCP because I have tried to configure the IP as static.

Comment: not sure if it is related. But, I've had a file named "hyphen" within my home directory under firefox, where it was hard linked to 127.0.0.1:<port>. It's entirely possible that 127 has been taken over by malware.

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is my expected DNS server in this case.   I'm running `dnsmasq` locally so that I can hardcode names for the machines on the local network and share them with my laptop.

Comment: have you checked your logs, or debugged the command that's changing the file?

Comment: When I run `resolveconf -u` it doesn't add anything to the syslog that I have been able to find, nor do I know of any other log files that it might use.

Comment: Look in the files under /run/resolvconf/interface. The line "search example.com" or "domain example.com" probably appears in one of those files. The name of the file indicates the source of the information.

Comment: That looks promising @jdthood.  ` /run/resolvconf/interface/NetworkManager` has a line in it with the incorrect information.   Should I be editing that file to remove it, or do I need to reconfigure the settings for NetworkManager elsewhere?

Comment: Editing that file won't do any good: it's a dynamic file that gets created every time NetworkManager configures a connection. The name "example.com" has been supplied to resolvconf by NetworkManager. So you just have to figure out where NetworkManager is getting it from. ;)

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Regarding "It is possible that a DHCP server is providing it, but I'm not sure how to check that" -- `nmcli --terse connection show <nmconnection>` includes what's in the `.nmconnection` file plus what comes back from the DHCP server.

Answer (score 3):

For ipv4, @stalet's suggestion to edit `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf` should work; also try removing `domain-search` and `domain-name` from the `request`.  Verify the settings worked in `/var/lib/NetworkManager/dhclient-[connection-uuid]-[ifname].lease`.

However, the unwanted search domain may be coming from the ipv6 dhcp server, as I found on 16.04/Xenial.  If NetworkManager's `dhclient -6` command succeeds and the dhcp server sets search domains, NetworkManager will merge those into the ipv4 search domain list.

A simple way to fix this on a connection-by-connection basis is to configure the connection's ipv6 settings to "Method: Automatic, addresses only" or even "Method:  Ignore".

Setting this for each connection could become annoying, and I looked pretty hard but couldn't find a way to fix this globally.  Adding `supersede dhcp6.domain-search` to and removing `request dhcp6.domain-search` from `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf` doesn't seem to help.  Also, copying that file to `/etc/dhcp/dhclient6.conf` caused NetworkManager to correctly template it to `/var/lib/NetworkManager/dhclient6-[ifname].conf`, but NetworkManager insists on adding `also request dhcp6.domain-search;`, and the unwanted search domain is still added.

Comment: just removing `domain-name` from the request then doing `ifdown eth0 && ifup eth0` worked for me on amazon EC2

Answer (score 2):

The `search` content is provided by dhcp, and can be overridden in `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf` by supersede these variables with empty values.

Add these lines at the bottom of the `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf`

```
supersede domain-name "";
supersede domain-search "";
supersede search "";
```

To make the change affect your system you can reconnect to your network or just restart the network-manager service.

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Comment: Even after following those instructions, `example.com` remains in the `search` section of `/etc/resolve.conf`.

Comment: Same. In my case I've tried to add search entries with prepend/append search and this had no effect on it.

Answer (score 0):

I saw an update to resolveconf 1.78ubuntu5 today (https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/+source/resolvconf/+changelog), referencing this Launchpad bug, https://bugs.launchpad.net/maas/+bug/1711760. Perhaps this issue is resolved now?